# Multiple folder generation and file writing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, batch-file

Here's is the reposted code to the suggestions

I have an image reading code in Matlab, which maps the pixel as a integer value in a text file.(.dat)

Next step is to read images from a folder and make a corresponding folder and save the .dat file in that folder.

For e.g 1.tif is saved as batch/1/1.dat
2.tif is saved as batch/2/2.dat and so on

Here is my MATLAB function

function createDAT(numFiles,source)

```
tic
for i=1:numFiles
    source_folder = [source];
    destination_folder = [num2str(i)];
    mkdir(destination_folder);

    img_name = [num2str(i) '.tif'];
    dat_filename = [num2str(i) '.dat'];

    source_path = fullfile(source_folder, img_name);
    destination_path = fullfile(source_folder, destination_folder, dat_filename);

    disp(destination_path);
    disp(source_path);


    file_id = fopen(fullfile(destination_path), 'w'); 
    disp(file_id);
    BB=imread(source_path ,'TIF');


    nx=size(BB,2);
    ny=size(BB,1);
    B=zeros(ny,nx);
%     wholeGeom=zeros(ny,nx);
    wholeGeom=BB;

    for i=1:nx
        for j=1:ny
                 if (wholeGeom(j,i) == 255)
                    B(j,i) = 1;
                 elseif (wholeGeom(j,i) == 0)
                    B(j,i) = 0;
                 end
        end
    end


'printing first slice'
fprintf(file_id, '%i\n', B);
%fwrite(outid, B);
fclose(file_id);

image(30*B)
axis equal
drawnow

end

toc
```

and the output indicated that the string are OK. But the error still persists. I wonder if it has to to do something with the file id as its displayed as negative value

```
>> createDAT(5,'batch')
Warning: Directory already exists. 
> In createDAT at 7 
batch/1/1.dat
batch/1.tif
    -1


ans =

printing first slice

Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in createDAT (line 42)
fprintf(file_id, '%i\n', B);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is there any error in the code?

Comment: Ooops, reposted the error

Comment: `fullfile(par1, part2,.....,partN)` should result into a full file name. Have you checked the path and made sure that the file extension and the path (including silly things like back slashes etc.) are correct. When you have `\`, ` you need to escape it by `"\\"`  I would start by printing the built filename from `fullfile` and making sure that the file actually exists.

Comment: Please check the content of the variables in the debugger, at least `destinationname = [i '/'];` is obviously wrong because it creates two doubles. Instead of using `/` use `fullfile` to create valid path names.